# passing data to yiistrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I want to pass data from cgridview button to yiistap modal. I have have gone through earlier questions on stackoverflow regarding how to pass value to Bootstrap modal. I tried similarly for yiistrap also but it is not working.

```
//cgridview buttons code which opens dashboard created using yiistrap modal.
'buttons'=>array (
            'Open Dashboard' => array ( 
                'options' => array(
                        'data-toggle'=>'modal', 
                        'data-target' => '#myModal', 
                        'data-id' => '$data->siteID',
                        'csrf' => true,
                ), 
                'icon' => 'briefcase',
            ),
        ),


     //code in modal-body
     <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){   
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var myBookId = $this.data(\'id\');
                        $("#bookId").val(myBookId);
                }
            );
            </script>
```

Now problem is that myBookId is always null. So can anyone suggest me where I am making mistake? 
Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ujhGX/ I have created. I need to show data-id.

Comment: This code makes no sense. What do you expect `var $this = $(this);` to be? what element do you expect $(this) to refer?

Comment: I am just starting with javascript so I have come up with this code by reading older posts but what is so wrong with $this = $(this)? As far as I know $this is normal variable in javascript and for $(this).data() you can search on google many results will come up. var $this = $(this) might be unnecessary step but it is not a wrong code. Correct me if I am wrong since I am new to javascript. I want to pass data-id to yiistrap modal.

Comment: `$this = $(this)` is used often, yes. But in the context you wrote it doesn't make sense. When you use that code it stores the value of `$(this)`, not store the function `$(this)` or run as if you wrote `$(this)` on different objects/elements. Please post more html so we can help you more.

Comment: I am not using html anywhere, I am using only php or javascript. Should I post relevant html code generated from this php code.

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle with your code. It's not clear what you need to fix.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ujhGX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myBookId = $('a[csrf="1"]').data('id');
    $("#bookId").val(myBookId);
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujhGX/1/)

Comment: Can you have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/ujhGX/2/. Clicking on both icon displays the same value. Modal should show different values.

Comment: @user2673943, your code is still very unclear. Check what is common to all those `<a>` elements and use that in the selector. Adding a class would be good. Then remove that inline script and use a click handler like in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ujhGX/3/